# How to add an instance method from inside of a class method which accepts a block to be executed in the context of the instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, memoization

I've entirely reworded this question as I feel this more accurately reflects what I wanted to ask the first time in a less roundabout way.

After instantiating a FormObject, calls to dynamically defined methods do not evaluate their block parameter in the context I'm trying for. For example:

```
@registration = RegistrationForm.new
@registration.user
# undefined local variable or method `user_params' for RegistrationForm:Class
```

RegistrationForm calls a class method `exposing(:user) { User.new(user_params) }` which I would like to have define a new method that looks like this:

```
def user
  @user ||= User.new(user_params)
end
```

My implementation doesn't use `@ivar ||=` to cache the value (since falsey values will cause the method to be re-evaluated). I borrowed the idea from rspec's memoized_helpers and I 'think' I understand how it works. What I don't understand is what I should replace `class_eval` with in `lib/form_object/memoized_helpers.rb`.

Thank you

**lib/form_object/base.rb**

```
class FormObject::Base
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include FormObject::MemoizedHelpers

  attr_reader :params, :errors

  def initialize(params = {})
    @params = ActionController::Parameters.new(params)
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  def save
    valid? && persist
  end
end
```

**lib/form_object/memoized_helpers.rb**

```
module FormObject
  module MemoizedHelpers
    private
    def __memoized
      @__memoized ||= {}
    end

    def self.included(mod)
      mod.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def exposing(name, &block)
        raise "#exposing called without a block" unless block_given?

        class_eval do
          define_method(name) { __memoized.fetch(name) { |k| __memoized[k] = block.call } }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/forms/registration_form.rb**

```
class RegistrationForm < FormObject::Base
  exposing(:user)   { User.new(user_params) { |u| u.is_admin = true } }
  exposing(:tenant) { user.build_tenant(tenant_params) }

  validate do
    tenant.errors.each do |key, value|
      errors.add("#{tenant.class.name.underscore}_#{key}", value)
    end unless tenant.valid?
  end

  validate do
    user.errors.each do |key, value|
      errors.add("#{user.class.name.underscore}_#{key}", value)
    end unless user.valid?
  end

  private

  def persist
    user.save
  end

  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def tenant_params
    params.fetch(:tenant, {}).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: The trouble, I think is going to be in #exposing.  I think we need to know more about its implementation.

Comment: Something was telling me I should have inlined all my code in the question rather than separating it. I didn't know how appropriate it was to have it all crammed inline though. All the code I've currently written can be found at the gist at the beginning of the question.

https://gist.github.com/frankjmattia/0096f7436a14d95b5ed9

Comment: External links tend to go bad, rending questions and answers that rely upon them meaningless.  Do you think you could pare it down to a minimal subset that reproduces the problem, and post it here (or is it already minimal?)

Comment: It's quite minimal. Only the three relatively short classes totaling ~80 LOC that I need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will edit my question to include the code linked in the gist.

Comment: erm, isn't it just using `instance_eval`?

Comment: `instance_eval` results in the same error I'm currently seeing using `class_eval`.

Comment: @phoet is there a specific way of applying `instance_eval` to this situation that I don't understand? My knowledge of using evals to this point in time have been mostly a need-to-know basis. If I simplify my define_method to skip memoization and change to `instance_eval { define_method(name) { block.call } }` I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I might have simplified this example too much, but I think this is what you want:

```
module Exposing
  def exposing(name, &block)
    instance_eval do
      define_method(name, block)
    end
  end
end

class Form
  extend Exposing

  exposing(:user) { user_params }

  def user_params
    {:hi => 'ho'}
  end
end

Form.new.user
```

You can fiddle around here: http://repl.it/OCa

Comment: This gets me very close and is almost a perfect answer. Could you  memoize the created method, either by caching the result of the block in the __memoized hash or perhaps a simpler method if you could suggest one?

Comment: i usually just give "help yourself" answers. the rest is homework, you know?

Comment: I guess that's fair enough and I typically enjoy those kinds of challenges. I guess at this point there's something fundamental about blocks I'm not seeing but I'll keep fooling around with it. Since you have offered the most acceptable answer I'll mark it as such. Thankya.

Comment: after reading the define_method doc for the 100th time I realized that it evaluates the passed in block using instance_eval... so, I applied your answer to my original code. It was simply a matter of changing my `class_eval` to `instance_eval` as you said and then replacing `block.call` with `instance_eval(&block)`. Worked like a charm. Thank you again.

Comment: @FrankJosephMattia nice!